# Bash/GitBash syntax for multiple variable value assignment not working when value is a command's output

Tags: bash, shell, git-bash, multiple-assignment

I have GitforWindows 2.20.1 installed in Windows 7 64Bit.

Now as I stated in the question, the multiple variable assignment syntax is not always working, especially when the value to be assigned is a command's output, i.e.:

```
read -r a b c <<< $(echo 1 2 3) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"
```

works, but these doesn't:

```
read -r SCRIPTDIR MAGE2ROOT <<< $(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
## OR ##
read -r -d "\n" SCRIPTDIR MAGE2ROOT <<< $(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
```

cause if I print the output just after this like:

```
echo $SCRIPTDIR && echo $MAGE2ROOT && exit
```

it just prints the path once. Why? And how can we make it work ?

Any help/guidance required.

Comment: What are you expecting `MAGE2ROOT` to be set to? `cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd` only prints one thing.

Comment: That is a way to get the running script's directory, I want `SCRIPTDIR` & `MAGE2ROOT`, both to store that same value simultaneously...

Comment: But the command only prints one thing. Just set the second var afterwards: `MAGE2ROOT="$SCRIPTDIR"`

Answer (score 0):

`read` doesn't do what you want it to. If it doesn't read as many "words" as there are variables to assign, it just leaves the extra variables blank. In this case, it's only getting one word (the path to the script's directory), but it has two variables to assign (`SCRIPTDIR` and `MAGE2ROOT`), so it sets `SCRIPTDIR` to the path, and `MAGE2ROOT` is left blank. Try your first example, but without supplying enough values to fill in all the variables:

```
$ read -r a b c <<< $(echo 1 2 3) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"
1|2|3
$ read -r a b c <<< $(echo 1 2) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"
1|2|
$ read -r a b c <<< $(echo 1) ; echo "$a|$b|$c"
1||
```

Fortunately, this is easy to solve (as @OlliK said) with `MAGE2ROOT="$SCRIPTDIR"`. Actually, there's no point in using `read` at all, just use a plain assignment:

```
SCRIPTDIR=$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)
MAGE2ROOT="$SCRIPTDIR"
```